# Как работать с сайтом через curl?

Tags: php, парсер, curl, file-get-contents

У меня получилось залогиниться на сайте через curl через такой код:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'www.site.name/?enterAgree=1';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url ); // отправляем на
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // пустые заголовки
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // возвратить то что вернул сервер
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // следовать за редиректами
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);// таймаут4
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt'); // сохранять куки в файл
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,  dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // использовать данные в post
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
  'LoginForm[password]'=>'123456789',
  'LoginForm[username]'=>'user_name_there',
  'YII_CSRF_TOKEN'=>'static_certificate_there'
));
curl_close($ch);
```

У меня сохранились куки с сайта в файл.И что делать дальше, если я хочу работать с этим сайтом, но по другой ссылке(допустим зайти в другой раздел под этими же куками, т.е. своим юзером )и под полученными куками?Просто если не использовать куки, то после перехода по любой ссылке сразу выкидывает плашку(отдельной страницей) с кнопкой, которую надо нажать для ридеректа(ее можно обойти, но не всегда путем вставки в конец url'a ?enterAgree=1).

Answer (score 0):

После того как залогнились и получили куки, их надо использовать в запросах, для этого:
1. Подавать куки которые у вас сохранены на все страницы к которым будете обращаться.
2. Можно не закрывать сессию curl_close();

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'www.site.name/?makesomething=1';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url ); // отправляем на
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // возвратить то что вернул сервер
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // следовать за редиректами
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);// таймаут4
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,  dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // использовать данные в post
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
  'DoSomething'=>'downloaddata'
));
```